# Java: making object "fit" with type where base class implements no interface and can't be inherited from

Tags: java, oop, testing, inheritance, twilio

I am using the Twilio library and specifically I'm trying to inject a mock of TwilioRestClient when testing.

It doesn't implement any interface. And I can't add one.

I can't inherit from it, it does stuff in the constructor I'm not a fan of.

I need to have a couple of methods in the mock that override or replace certain behavior of TwilioRestClient.

How do I do this?

I have tried inner anonymous classes to no avail. I have tried subclassing but obviously doesn't work. Any Java guru out there?

edit, version of twilio sdk;

```
public class TwilioRestClient {
    /** The Constant VERSION. */
    private static final String VERSION = "3.3.15";
```

constructors:

```
    /**
 * Explcitly construct a TwilioRestClient with the given API credentials.
 *
 * @param accountSid
 *            the 34 character Account identifier (starting with 'AC'). This
 *            can be found on your Twilio dashboard page.
 * @param authToken
 *            the 32 character AuthToken. This can be found on your Twilio
 *            dashboard page.
 *
 */
public TwilioRestClient(String accountSid, String authToken) {
    this(accountSid, authToken, null);
}

/**
 * Explcitly construct a TwilioRestClient with the given API credentials and
 * endpoint.
 *
 * @param accountSid
 *            the 34 character Account identifier (starting with 'AC'). This
 *            can be found on your Twilio dashboard page.
 * @param authToken
 *            the 32 character AuthToken. This can be found on your Twilio
 *            dashboard page.
 * @param endpoint
 *            the url of API endpoint you wish to use. (e.g. -
 *            'https://api.twilio.com')
 */
public TwilioRestClient(String accountSid, String authToken, String endpoint) {

    validateAccountSid(accountSid);
    validateAuthToken(authToken);

    this.accountSid = accountSid;
    this.authToken = authToken;

    if ((endpoint != null) && (!endpoint.equals(""))) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    //Grab the proper connection manager, based on runtime environment
    ClientConnectionManager mgr = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest");
        mgr = new AppEngineClientConnectionManager();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //Not GAE
        mgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager();
        ((ThreadSafeClientConnManager) mgr).setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
    }

    setHttpclient(new DefaultHttpClient(mgr));
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version",
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout",
            new Integer(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT));
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout",
            new Integer(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT));
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset",
            "UTF-8");

    this.authAccount = new Account(this);
    this.authAccount.setSid(this.accountSid);
    this.authAccount.setAuthToken(this.authToken);

}
```

Comment: By definition, you're not going to be able to _override_ any methods without inheritance.

Comment: You are right. What I intend is to make sure when what I'm testing is calling those methods, I decide in the test what the methods will return. Basically just injecting behavior, somehow.

Comment: Try jmockit to redefine methods.

Comment: I'm using mockito but get weird behavior when mocking this class amongst others. I would like to solve this without using a test/mock framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an abstraction layer to hide all the twilio specific logic and to make the code more testable. There was no other way to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You would like to avoid using a mock framework, and you don't want to extend/override TwilioRestClient.

A "pure java" way to do this, then, might be to have your class which uses TwilioRestClient instead use an interface you define. The difficulty of this depends on how much of the TwilioRestClient interface you're actually using.

If you're using only a few methods, define your own interface, for example:

```
public interface RestClient {
    String get(String uri);
}
```

When you want to use the TwilioRestClient, you can:

```
final TwilioRestClient trc = createTwilioRestClient();
myService.setRestClient(new RestClient() {
    public String get(String uri) {
        return trc.get(uri);
    }
});
```

When you want to unit test, use:

```
myService.setRestClient(new RestClient() {
    public String get(String uri) {
        return someMockData();
    }
});
```

This will get unwieldy if you're using a lot of the interface, though; in that case, mock libraries are really your best bet, this is what they're for.

Comment: interesting approach, I will research this option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see `TwilioRestClient` is not a final class, so you have no problems to extend it and override every not privete method.

Second, here is the source code of `TwilioRestClient` I found [here](https://code.google.com/p/ew-samples/source/browse/trunk/sandbox/FlightBookingMobile/src/com/twilio/sdk/TwilioRestClient.java?r=31):

```
private String endpoint = "https://api.twilio.com";
private String accountSid;
private String authToken;


public TwilioRestClient(String accountSid, String authToken, String endpoint) {

    this.accountSid = accountSid;
    this.authToken = authToken;
    if((endpoint!=null)&&(!endpoint.equals(""))){
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }
}
```

As we can seem it just initializes three string fields into the constructor. So, I think that you can send there any arguments that you want and even do not have to extend the class. I am however not sure that the source code I found belongs to the same version that you are using. You have not specified the version.

The only limitation you have here is that you cannot initialize `endopoint` to empty string that sounds good. But if you want to do something like that you can do this using reflection once instance is created.

Comment: Thanks, I will update my question with the version. It doesn't look the same.

Comment: Well, so what kind of changes of constructor behavior you need?

Comment: Basically I could override all of the methods called in the constructor to get to the point I want to be. However, it would be preferable to not have to do that, as in some cases, not this one specifically, that can be quite tedious. I'm probably not thinking Java enough, as I'm more used to replacing behaviour on the fly in typeless languages like Ruby.

Comment: So, @Phil, you understand your problem yourself. Do not try to replace functionality on the fly. You can do it but it is the way to hell. Create subclass, override what you need and use your subclass. If you want you always can call `super.foo()` from your overridden version of `foo()`. You can also do it conditionally, so in some cases your subclass will behavior like its base class. If you still want some "dynamic" replacement you can take a look on byte code modification and agents but again, do it only if other ways do not work.